# PHP Error parsing XML (simpleXML)

Tags: php, xml, parsing, error-handling, simplexml

i have a xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>Total</test>
<books>
    <mybook id="1">
        <blabla>jkjk</blabla>
    </mybook>¨
</books>
```

If I parse it like that with simpleXML

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
```

it says

```
simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ./uploads/test.xml:3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
```

But if a remove the

```
<test>Total</test>
```

at the begining of the xml file it works....

any ideas ??
thank you

Answer (score 14):

You need to have a root element in your xml, i.e.

```
<document>
    <test>Total</test>
    <books>
        <mybook id="1">
            <blabla>jkjk</blabla>
        </mybook>
    </books>
</document>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is what it writes. Extra content.

And what is it? `¨` after `</mybook>`. So the file isn't valid. If you want it valid, it'd look like:

```
    <bookinfo>
   <test>Total</test>
    <books>
        <mybook id="1">
            <blabla>jkjk</blabla>
        </mybook>
    </books>
    </bookinfo>
```

A note: an XML has to be always ONE, exactly one root element.

Comment: Whoever minussed this: Why? This is totally correct answer. Nearly same as Petter's (+4), but one minutes *before*. Any reason? I want to know.

Comment: @axiomer I downvoted this prior to your correction, but didn't return before I could remove it and saw the correction. A shallow edit will fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is invalid. XML must have one and only one root element.

The "extra content" the parser is complaining about is the `<books>` element.